# Adding angular.morris-chart to angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, morris.js

I'm trying to draw some donut charts with angular.morris-chart.js in my angular app.But when i can't figure out how to add it.
I added the js file in my libs directory, added it in my index.html after angular call. And i also injected it in my app.
But it still doesn't work. I get this error in my browser console: 'ReferenceError: Morris is not defined'.
Any clue to solve my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ng-morris :

https://github.com/cleechtech/ng-morris

Comment: I saw this, but they recommend to use angular.morris-chart.js, cause they are not maintened anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
Include in your project-'raphael/raphael.js','morris.js/morris.js', 'angular-morris-chart/src/angular-morris-chart.js','morris.js/morris.css'
```

These files will be in your bower_components after the bower install angular-morris-chart.

Answer (score 0):

You should move to [Angular-Morris](https://angular-morris.io/). I have used it in Angular 1.3 and 1.5 perfectly.

It is really easy to use.

Add these:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-morris/1.3.0/angular-morris.min.js"></script>
```

Inject the dependency to your module:

```
'angular.morris'
```

Then just use it in your template:

```
<div
bar-chart 
bar-data='[
    { y: "2006", a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: "2007", a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: "2008", a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: "2009", a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: "2010", a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: "2011", a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: "2012", a: 100, b: 90 }
]'
bar-x='y'
bar-y='["a", "b"]'
bar-labels='["Series A", "Series B"]'
bar-colors='["#31C0BE", "#c7254e"]'>
</div>
```

Once it shows up, start passing values from controller.

`bar-data =<controller>.arrayname` (stringify if required)